# Order of fields in filter criteria section while creating a new view

Tags: list-view

We have around 148 fields on contact object and when we try to create a new view , the fields are displayed all over the drop down in filter criteria section

[image]

Is there any logic on order of fields? If yes, Is there a way i can get alphabetic sort of fields?

Comment: Person Accounts?

Comment: No. Not personal accounts

Comment: I think we can not set filter on 'Select Field' while creating a list view, we can go to that field by pressing the first letter of that field. Example :- As in screen Shot A field 'Report to', to search this Just press 'R', and your pointer will automatically point to that field.